# What does an integral with only one integration limit mean?

Tags: notation

I am supervising an end of degree project related to Sturm-Liouville problems. In the paper [Singular Sturm comparison theorems](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82445198.pdf) I saw the next strange integrals in *Theorem 1*:

> Let $P(x)$, $p(x)$ be continuous functions on the open, finite or infinite interval $(a,b)$ (but not necessarily at its endpoints), and $P(x)\geq p(x)$, $P (x)\not\equiv p(x)$ on $(a, b)$.
>   (i) Suppose that the differential equation
>   $$u′′+p(x)u=0,\quad a<x<b,$$ 
>   has a solution $u$ which satisfies the boundary conditions
>    $$\int_a\frac{dx}{u^2(x)}=\infty,\ \int^b\frac{dx}{u^2(x)}=\infty.$$

In the paper, there is no explanation about how they are defined.
There is one reference in the paper to the book *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Philip Hartman. In this book, the notation is used extensively but I could neither found their definition.

My thoughts: they don't seem to be primitives; they neither seem to be improper integrals in an infinite interval.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: This is a just a guess, but the notation suggests the following interpretation to me $$\int_a f(x)dx=\lim_{c\to a+}\int_c^d f(x)dx,$$ and similarly for the other.  Does this make sense in context?

Comment: IMO, "near $x=a$" and "near $x=b$". As the integral diverges at $a$ and $b$, the other bound is unimportant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, thank you very much for your answer. I think that this make sense.